# SQL Sum returning wrong number

Tags: sql

I am adding up the amount of tickets sold for a sporting event, the answer should be under 100 but my answer is in the thousands.

```
SELECT Stubhub.Active.Opponent, 
       SUM(Stubhub.Active.Qty) AS AQty, SUM(Stubhub.Sold.Qty) AS SQty
FROM   Stubhub.Active INNER JOIN
       Stubhub.Sold ON Stubhub.Active.Opponent = Stubhub.Sold.Opponent
GROUP BY Stubhub.Active.Opponent
```

Comment: Did you try `COUNT` instead of `SUM`?

Comment: i did, the numbers were still in the thousands but not as high

Comment: in that case you are doing something wrong with your join. what if you get count of all records in Sold without join to Active?

Comment: the problem is definitely in the join, running each sum function alone produces the right number

Comment: include your sample data, and expected output?

Comment: @L.Snow include your table definitions, you should have different column that should be used to join.

Comment: What is Opponent? Probably you should be joining on TransactionID or something instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is type of problem occurs because you are getting a cartesian product between each table for each opponent.  The solution is to pre-aggregate by opponent:

```
SELECT a.Opponent, a.AQty, s.SQty
FROM (SELECT a.Opponent, SUM(a.Qty) as AQty
      FROM Stubhub.Active a
      GROUP BY a.Opponent
     ) a INNER JOIN
     (SELECT s.Opponent, SUM(s.QTY) as SQty
      FROM Stubhub.Sold s
      GROUP BY s.Opponent
     ) s
     ON a.Opponent = s.Opponent;
```

Notice that in this case, you do not need the aggregation in the outer query.